# Function returns multidimensional array with the same values per line, instead of the different values per line calculated with the function

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a function that for every entry in SCounts samples the value amount of times from values ranging from 0 to 10 with the weights from the array FS and then rebins them back into a range from 0 to 10 (this works). (NOTE: for my actual code the channelnumbers and length of SCounts are much larger). When I print this list inside the n-loop the values are different (as expected), while outside the n-loop these get overwritten to the final array (see output), which is not what I aim for. I can't seem to figure out why this happens, any help is much appreciated.

```
import random
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

FS = [7.23900537e+01, 3.20399585e+02, 7.87859277e+01, 7.13517144e+02, 3.65143642e+02, 2.13185063e+02, 2.14225579e+02, 2.00109435e+02, 1.80659967e+02, 1.63896939e+02]
SCounts = [5277.872472199431, 5646.015740911809, 4864.201935526552, 5258.38505381198, 3850.1494907432266]
channelNumbers = 10

def Samp(SCounts,FS):
    tot = np.sum(FS)
    channels = range(channelNumbers) 
    spectra = [[0]*channelNumbers]*len(SCounts) 
    for n in range(len(SCounts)): #n-loop
        values = random.choices(channels, weights = FS/tot,k=round(SCounts[n]))
        #Count the number of times a channel number occurs 
        counter = Counter(values)   
        #Fill list per channel with the number of counts         
        for i in range(channelNumbers):            
            spectra[n][i] = counter.get(i+1)            
        print(spectra[n])        
    print("Outside n-loop:")
    print(spectra[0])
    print(spectra[4])
    return spectra   

spectra = Samp(SCounts,FS)
```

Output:

```
[693, 167, 1469, 754, 446, 455, 426, 375, 346, None]
[678, 167, 1663, 803, 519, 464, 427, 398, 375, None]
[581, 134, 1376, 757, 383, 451, 359, 355, 309, None]
[667, 159, 1491, 757, 425, 473, 399, 397, 335, None]
[494, 123, 1052, 569, 339, 308, 295, 266, 275, None]
Outside n loop:
[494, 123, 1052, 569, 339, 308, 295, 266, 275, None]
[494, 123, 1052, 569, 339, 308, 295, 266, 275, None]
```

Comment: `spectra = [[0]*channelNumbers]*len(SCounts) ` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: "I can't seem to figure out why this happen": have you tried some simple debugging? For example, printing out intermediate values at various places in the function?

Comment: Changing this indeed solved it, thank you!